# ReactNative how should this be written?

Tags: react-native, expo, gluestack

I try to build my first serious app in ReactNativ but it's my first time with it. I build some basic components but i'm not sure if it's properly written. I used Expo and GlueStackUI + Navigation. Could you help me and check it out? It would be good for me to see fixed code aswell to learn.

https://github.com/MichalBartusiak/eventApp.git

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately your question is off-topic here - this site is more for specific solutions to technical problems. You would probably have more luck on the [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) site.